# Why isn't north Quebec a little warmer?

Tags: climatology

[image: http://bonap.org/Climate%20Maps/hardiness2.png]

When I saw this map I was surprised to learn that part of Quebec is in the worst winter hardiness zone of North America (including Greenland). Zone 0a, which is defined as "average winters get colder than 65 below F." Also, why is it warmer north of Jaques Cartier Strait than the rest of the St. Lawrence? Shouldn't the nearby land (Ile d'Anticosti) make it slightly colder?

Comment: If I'm reading your map right, the cold spot in the center of Quebec province.    High altitude likely plays a role.   see map here:   https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e8/28/ea/e828eac639f33a7fdd6beb04558e7b3a.jpg